# What does one do about buggy POSIX APIs which leak memory?

Tags: posix, valgrind, system-calls

Disclaimer: This is for an assignment, but the assignment doesn't require that we remove memory leaks. I'm just anal retentive on this one.

Consider the following method:

```
//Prints the current user ID to the console.
void PrintUserId()
{
        std::cout << "Current User Id: " << cuserid(0) << std::endl;
}
```

The docs for `cuserid` state:

> If string is not a null pointer, it should be an array that can hold at least L_cuserid  characters; the string is returned in this array.  Otherwise, a pointer to a string in a static area is returned.

But at least on my system, the memory in question doesn't appear to be statically allocated (or at least there are bugs...):

```
(Valgrind Output)
==4488== 160 (40 direct, 120 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11 of 11
==4488==    at 0x4025BD3: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==4488==    by 0x4247A9C: nss_parse_service_list (nsswitch.c:622)
==4488==    by 0x4248216: __nss_database_lookup (nsswitch.c:164)
==4488==    by 0x402DEAB: ???
==4488==    by 0x402EB6C: ???
==4488==    by 0x41FE41C: getpwuid_r@@GLIBC_2.1.2 (getXXbyYY_r.c:253)
==4488==    by 0x41A2785: cuserid (cuserid.c:38)
==4488==    by 0x80495A3: PrintUserId() (in /home/bro4/Assignment1.bin)
==4488==    by 0x8049A11: ParentProcess() (in /home/bro4/Assignment1.bin)
==4488==    by 0x8049B53: main (in /home/bro4/Assignment1.bin)
```

Am I just stuck on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a false positive. `cuserid` or its dependencies could allocate a buffer on its first call, then free or reuse it on the next call. Try calling it in a loop; do you end up with multiple leak reports?

In your case, the allocation is done by [nss_parse_service_list](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#EDsXRboMUCE/pub/mirrors/kernel.org/software/libs/glibc/glibc-2.1.2.tar.bz2%7CdkRxx4-EtBo/glibc-2.1.2/nss/nsswitch.c&q=file%3agetpwuid_r.c%20glibc-2.1.2&d=8&l=575), part of the nsswitch internal API that handles switching between various authentication providers (unix /etc/passwd, LDAP, etc). This function is called by [__nss_database_lookup](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#EDsXRboMUCE/pub/mirrors/kernel.org/software/libs/glibc/glibc-2.1.2.tar.bz2%7CdkRxx4-EtBo/glibc-2.1.2/nss/nsswitch.c&q=file%3agetpwuid_r.c%20glibc-2.1.2&d=8&l=126), which calls it as part of a *one-time* initialization process. So this isn't really a leak; it's memory that's allocated to hold the results of parsing a config file (or, in this case, a default config). It won't be freed, because it's needed until the program terminates; but neither will it grow.

Since this is a false positive, you may want to [suppress these reports](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) in valgrind. It's not uncommon to see valgrind warnings from system libraries - there are one-time allocations like this in various library routines, as well as low-level routines doing things that look to valgrind like a potential problem, when in fact they're very carefully controlled and correct. It's best to suppress them - after, of course, checking that they're not really your fault, of course!

Comment: yes, I just reached the same conclusion on the ultimate source of the allocation in nss_parse_service_list.

Comment: Not sure I would call that a "false positive" -- IMHO, that's leaked, even if it's for a buffer used for static-like data. After all, that's what __libc_freeres is for. But +1 and checkmark.

Comment: I, for one, don't consider data that's needed until program termination to be leaked (as long as it doesn't grow without bounds) - the only problem this causes is false positives hiding real, growing-without-bounds leaks. That said if this isn't freed be __libc_freeres it might be worth filing a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

The [Single UNIX ® Specification, Version 2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/cuserid.html) does not guarantee that static data will be used, it says it "may be static".

> If s is a null pointer, this
>   representation is generated in an area
>   that may be static (and thus
>   overwritten by subsequent calls to
>   cuserid()), the address of which is
>   returned.

The linux man page for cuserid() has two provocative statements:

> The cuserid function was included in the 1988 version of POSIX, but removed from the 1990 version.

and

> Nobody knows precisely what cuserid() does - avoid it in portable
>   programs - avoid it altogether - use
>   getpwuid(geteuid()) instead, if  that 
>   is  what  you
>          meant.  DO NOT USE cuserid().

Assuming the statement that this function was removed from POSIX more than 20 years ago is accurate, I would say "DO NOT USE cuserid()" is pretty good advice. Failing that, pass a pointer to cuserid and manage the memory yourself.

Comment: Passing my own pointer does not fix the leak. (Valgrind output is unchanged it I use a stack allocated buffer)

Comment: Interesting. Looking at the stack trace, it looks like cuserid is calling getpwuid_r internally; it would need to allocate a buffer to pass to getpwuid_r.

Comment: `cuserid()` uses a static buffer: http://goo.gl/SHhxs (but see my answer for the actual source of this allocation)